# v.surf.idw failling with "Killed" message on GRASS 7.8.2

Tags: grass-gis, nearest-neighbor

I have a categorical raster with gaps that I would like to fill using a nearest neighbour interpolation. The `r.fill.gaps` module does not implement this interpolation method so I am trying a manual approach, first creating a points vector from the original raster and then applying the `v.surf.idw` module (which implements the nearest neighbour method with the `npoints=1` argument). Problem is: `v.surf.idw` fails.

This is the original raster with gaps:

```
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > g.region -p
projection: 99 (unknown)
zone:       0
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      4289569.27224353
south:      -4452930.72775647
west:       -2226387.74484971
east:       6679312.25515029
nsres:      100
ewres:      100
rows:       87425
cols:       89057
cells:      7785808225

GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > r.info soil_map_rcl_no_water
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      soil_map_rcl_no_water          Date: Tue Apr 13 15:37:37 2021    |
 | Mapset:   MAL                            Login of Creator: duque004        |
 | Location: S4AHomolosine                                                    |
 | DataBase: /home/duque004/Work/GRASSDATA                                    |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    CELL                                                       |
 |   Rows:         87425                                                      |
 |   Columns:      89057                                                      |
 |   Total Cells:  7785808225                                                 |
 |        Projection: unknown                                                 |
 |            N: 4289569.27224353    S: -4452930.72775647   Res:   100        |
 |            E: 6679312.25515029    W: -2226387.74484971   Res:   100        |
 |   Range of data:    min = 1  max = 21                                      |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.mapcalc                                                  |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    if(soil_map_rcl == 2, null(), soil_map_rcl)                             |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From it I create a lower density points vector:

```
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > g.region nsres=2000 ewres=2000
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > r.to.vect type=point input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_no_water --overwrite
WARNING: Vector map <soil_map_rcl_no_water> already exists and will be
         overwritten
Extracting points...
 100%
Building topology for vector map <soil_map_rcl_no_water@MAL>...
Registering primitives...
r.to.vect complete.

GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > v.info soil_map_rcl_no_water
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Name:            soil_map_rcl_no_water                                     |
 | Mapset:          MAL                                                       |
 | Location:        S4AHomolosine                                             |
 | Database:        /home/duque004/Work/GRASSDATA                             |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Map scale:       1:1                                                       |
 | Name of creator: duque004                                                  |
 | Organization:                                                              |
 | Source date:     Wed Apr 14 09:32:59 2021                                  |
 | Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Map format:      native                                                    |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |   Type of map: vector (level: 2)                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Number of points:       7449385         Number of centroids:  0          |
 |   Number of lines:        0               Number of boundaries: 0          |
 |   Number of areas:        0               Number of islands:    0          |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Map is 3D:              No                                               |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: unknown                                                      |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:   4156561.6652886    S: -3875897.72615501                 |
 |               E:  6174329.26615411    W:  -1775402.9368551                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
 |   Comment:                                                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And finally to the interpolation:

```
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > g.region nsres=100 ewres=100
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > v.surf.idw npoints=1 input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_water_fill --overwrite
Killed
```

There are no other messages to pic from. Memory usage looks normal (32 GB RAM in this workstation). The next try was thus with a lower resolution output raster:

```
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > g.region nsres=2000 ewres=2000
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > v.surf.idw npoints=1 input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_water_fill --overwrite
[...]
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 7449381)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 7449382)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 7449383)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 7449384)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 7449385)
0 points loaded
ERROR: No points found
```

Third attempt, reducing even further the point density and the resolution of the resulting raster:

```
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > g.region nsres=20000 ewres=20000
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > r.to.vect type=point input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_no_water --overwrite
WARNING: Vector map <soil_map_rcl_no_water> already exists and will be
         overwritten
Extracting points...
 100%
Building topology for vector map <soil_map_rcl_no_water@MAL>...
Registering primitives...
r.to.vect complete.
GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > v.info soil_map_rcl_no_water
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Name:            soil_map_rcl_no_water                                     |
 | Mapset:          MAL                                                       |
 | Location:        S4AHomolosine                                             |
 | Database:        /home/duque004/Work/GRASSDATA                             |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Map scale:       1:1                                                       |
 | Name of creator: duque004                                                  |
 | Organization:                                                              |
 | Source date:     Wed Apr 14 10:31:42 2021                                  |
 | Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Map format:      native                                                    |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |   Type of map: vector (level: 2)                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Number of points:       74411           Number of centroids:  0          |
 |   Number of lines:        0               Number of boundaries: 0          |
 |   Number of areas:        0               Number of islands:    0          |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Map is 3D:              No                                               |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: unknown                                                      |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:  4139526.36606504    S: -3862761.96345441                 |
 |               E:  6168985.62593681    W: -1736073.92462499                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
 |   Comment:                                                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

GRASS 7.8.2 (S4AHomolosine):~ > v.surf.idw npoints=1 input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_water_fill --overwrite
[...]
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 74407)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 74408)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 74409)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 74410)
WARNING: No record for point (cat = 74411)
0 points loaded
ERROR: No points found
```

How can I use `v.surf.idw` with this GRASS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was identified in [this thread](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2021-April/082374.html) at the GRASS mail list.

The manual page for the `v.surf.idw` module states the following:

```
   **column**=name
       Name of attribute column with values to interpolate
       If not given and input is 2D vector map then category values are used. If input is 3D vector
       map then z-coordinates are used.
```

The points vector in question was generated by GRASS itself and includes the following columns:

```
 >  v.info -c soil_map_rcl_no_water
Displaying column types/names for database connection of layer <1>:
INTEGER|cat
INTEGER|value
CHARACTER|label
```

As it happens, neither `value`, nor `cat` are actually used as the default value column by `v.surf.idw`. The module is seeking for some other column (which?) and therefore it fails.

The solution is thus to pass the `value` column explicitly to the module:

```
> v.surf.idw npoints=1 column=value input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_water_fill --overwrite
114 points loaded
Interpolating raster map <soil_map_rcl_water_fill> (2430 rows, 2860
columns)...
 100%
v.surf.idw complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the question. I'll try to address some/most ;-)

First, the original question was filling NULL cells with a nearest neighbor calculation. You can consider to use the `r.neighbors` module for this, with the `selection` parameter. This allows to run `r.neighbors` only in pixels covered by the `selection` map. So first create the `selection` map with:

```
r.mapcalc "selection = if(isnull(soil_map_rcl_no_water), 1, null())"
```

This `selection` raster will have value 1 wherever the `soil_map_rcl_no_water` was null, and null otherwise.
Now you can run r.neighbors with whatever window size and aggregation you choose, and the `selection` map will insure that only null cells are treated:

```
r.neighbors input=soil_map_rcl_no_water output=soil_map_rcl_no_water_fill selection=selection size=11 method=average
```

I would add that there's the `r.fillnulls` module that fills NULL cells with spline interpolation. It's not clear why you are using a nearest neighbors method, so you might consider option this instead.

I would further add that IDW is **not** nearest neighbors, so that added confusion to your question. And what's more, using `npoints=1` makes no sense. You surely do not want to fill a null region with an IDW value derived from one single nearby point. The `v.surf.idw` module is typically used to interpolate an **irregular** distribution of points, which is **not** the case here. `r.to.vect` would create a regular grid of points.

And, what's more you must specify the `column` parameter to indicate which vector point value to use for the interpolation. In your case this would be "value", the default column created by `r.to.vect`.

To summarize, I think you want one of the more straightforward fill nulls options mentioned above, rather than some IDW interpolation.

Comment: Neither `r.fillnulls` nor `r.neighbours` provide a nearest neighbour operation. Moreover, both produce outputs outside of the input raster domain. Since these values are categories those methods are not an option. 

You can read the following in the manual page for [`v.surf.idw`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.surf.idw.html): "By setting **npoints=1**, the module can be used to calculate raster Voronoi diagrams (Thiessen polygons)." As far as I am aware, this is the only method available in GRASS to produce a raster with this kind of method.

Comment: I missed that you are working with a categorical raster. (Right at the beginning of your question. Sorry for misleading :-(